# Time Complexity of accessing element from vector vs unordered_map

Tags: c++, performance, greedy

I was solving a quetion on InterviewBit https://www.interviewbit.com/old/problems/largest-permutation/
When I solved this question using unordered_map to store the indices of elements in teh array it showed Time Limit Exceeded but using a vectr for the same thing somehow improved the time complexicity...!!
But accessing an element is also O(1) in unorderd_map
I added my code also incase there was a problem with my code to be corrected.

```cpp
vector<int> Solution::solve(vector<int> &A, int B) {
    int n=A.size();
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(A[i-1]>A[i])
            cnt++;
    }
    if(cnt==n-1)
        return A;
    
    vector<int>mp(n+1,-1);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        mp[A[i]]=i;
    }
    int i=0;
    int temp=n;
    while(i<n && temp>=1 && B!=0){
        if(A[i]!=temp){
        // {   cout<<A[i]<<" "<<temp<<endl;
            int x=A[i];
            A[i]=temp;
            A[mp[temp]]=x;
            mp[x]=mp[temp];
            mp[temp]=i;
            B=B-1;
        }
        i=i+1;
        temp=temp-1;
        
    }
    return A;
}
```

P.S. I also think the problem is with adding an element to a unordered_map vs a vector but i'm not quiet sure

Comment: The time complexity is somewhat the same, you need to consider the CPU cache hit ratio. For small data sets, vectors have a much higher cache hit ratio than hash maps.

Comment: Depending on the c++ standard template library implementation this is used with, you probably have hashes involving integer division in the `std::unordered_map`, whereas accessing an index of a `std::vector` typically involves shifting and adding, and multiplication at worst. Division can easily have ~100 times more latency than shift+add, and even worse throughput. You can't always ignore constant factors when looking at performance.

Comment: @EOF -- good point. It's important to understand that time complexity tells you how the time needed scales as the amount of data increases. That tells you nothing about the relative performance of two different approaches on the same data.